# Concatenation of int with string to TextView gives a set of Integer

Tags: android, string, textview

In my android app, I'm trying to set the text to a TextView with integer and a string value. I'm getting the length of the array and going to set it with a string value as below.

```
if (array.size() > 0) {
    textView.setText(array.size() + " " + R.string.lbl_text);
}
```

When I run the App it give me a set of integers as shown below:

```
1 2345223232
```

Then I covert array size to string as follow

```
if (array.size() > 0) {
    textView.setText(Integer.toString(array.size()) + " " + R.string.lbl_text);
}
```

But the same output. What is the reason for getting Integer value for the `string.lbl_text`

Comment: because `R.string.lbl_text` is an integer - you have to use `Resources` class to get the text from it

Comment: Use `getResources().getString(R.string.lbl_text)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Use getResources().getString(R.string.lbl_text) and then you would be able to access the string text. as @pskink told already
```

Answer (score 2):

`R.string.xxx` is a resource identifier. In order it to convert to a `String` value you need to call `getString()` on a `Resources` or `Context` instance:

```
resources.getString(R.string.xxx);
```